# Overwrite __sub__ for a-b when 'b' is my class

Tags: python

I have a class `foo` that is essentially a float with some extra attributes attached. I can overwrite its `__sub__` method so that I can do subtraction one direction, but I can't figure out how to do it the other way:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, value, otherstuff):
        self.value = value
        self.otherstuff = otherstuff

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.value - other

a = 5
b = foo(12, 'blue')
print b-a  # this works fine and returns 7
print a-b  # I want this to return -7 but it obviously doesn't work
```

Is there a way to do this?

A general solution for add, sub, mul, div would be ideal, but sub and div are most pressing since they're not reversible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to override `__rsub__`, for right-hand side subtraction:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, value, otherstuff):
        self.value = value
        self.otherstuff = otherstuff

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.value - other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return other - self.value
```

Output:

```
print(b - a)
7

print(a - b)
-7
```

There are similar methods like `__radd__`, `__rmul__` for other operations.

Comment: that should be 'subtraction', not 'substitution' :)